# getIdentities() what it does?

Tags: magento2, error, methods

I get a warrning on Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ListProduct->getIdentities()

```
Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()
```

I checked the specified method but I do not understand what does return

```
  /**
     * Return identifiers for produced content
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function getIdentities()
    {
        $identities = [];
        foreach ($this->_getProductCollection() as $item) {
            $identities = array_merge($identities, $item->getIdentities());
        }
        $category = $this->getLayer()->getCurrentCategory();
        if ($category) {
            $identities[] = Product::CACHE_PRODUCT_CATEGORY_TAG . '_' . $category->getId();
        }
        return $identities;
    }
```

locally I set var_dump() and die but is never getting touched

Comment: great thanks! now I know that is used for caching but still not know why this warning breaks the page

Comment: probably because `$this->_getProductCollection()` is empty or not an array

Comment: So on development I do not have page cache enabled the error is not present,  in a custom module I override the  _getProductCollection() method   to check for child products if there ar no  child product I return null, so how would I suppress this error?

Comment: Instead of returning null, return an empty array

Comment: I posted the solution as answer so you can close the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is most likely due to the fact that your custom module overriding `_getProductCollection()` method returns null.

If you return an empty array instead it should fix your problem.